# How to use new operator as mapped type in std::map?

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap

I've got a problem with `std::map`. I try to implement map that mapped type should return pointer to new created object. Better explanation in code below:

```
std::map<char, abstract_operation_factory*> operations_map = boost::assign::map_list_of
                                                  ('+', (new add_oper_factory))
                                                  ('-', (new sub_oper_factory));
char operation = '+';
std::map<char, abstract_operation_factory*>::const_iterator it = operations_map.find(operation);
if (it != operations_map.end()) {
    boost::shared_ptr<abstract_operation_factory> oper_factory(it->second);
}
```

I always get the same error from boost library.

```
/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/local.hpp:37: error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<char, add_oper_factory*>::pair(const char&, sub_oper_factory* const&)'
         BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(1)
         ^
```

Is an any option to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `map_list_of` sees this list...

```
('+', (new add_oper_factory))
('-', (new sub_oper_factory))
```

...it starts creating pairs based on the types of the first pair, but that then clashes with the type of the second pair.  If you cast both pointers to `abstract_operation_factory*` you'll get past that:

```
('+', static_cast<abstract_operation_factory*>(new add_oper_factory))
('-', static_cast<abstract_operation_factory*>(new sub_oper_factory))
```

That said, when you later create...

```
boost::shared_ptr<abstract_operation_factory> oper_factory(it->second);
```

...you're asking the `shared_ptr` to take ownership of the dynamically allocated object - when the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope it will `delete` the object without removing it from the `map`.  Perhaps you plan to take care of that, but if it's accidental you may want to instead store `shared_ptr`s in the `map` to too prevent this, or you may want to use `it->second` as a raw pointer without storing it in a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: You have got definetely right. So now, when I'll use shared_ptr in map in such a way: std::map<char, boost::shared_ptr<abstract_operation_factory> > operations_map = boost::assign::map_list_of
                                                  ('+', static_cast<abstract_operation_factory*>(new add_oper_factory))
                                                  ('-', static_cast<abstract_operation_factory*>(new sub_oper_factory)); references counter will increase during assignment in boost::shared_ptr<abstract_operation_factory> oper_factory = it->second; and everyting will be ok, right?

Comment: @Nowax: yes, that sounds solid to me.